# Is there a way to use .babelrc for development/testing environments, and SWC for production environment?

Tags: next.js, babeljs, cypress, code-coverage, istanbul

I am using a [Cypress code coverage plugin](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage#Instrumenting-code)  that depends on [istanbul](https://github.com/istanbuljs/babel-plugin-istanbul) which is [not supported by SWC](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/30529), so in order for it to work, I have it configured in a `.babelrc` file at the root of my Next.js project. I only need the plugin for dev/testing environments, so it's not needed for production environment. Is there a way to configure my Next.js project so it still opts in for SWC in production, and ignores the .babelrc in dev/testing environments?

Comment: It looks like that isn't true. Refer [jsc.preserveAllComments](https://swc.rs/docs/configuration/compilation#jscpreserveallcomments) - "This feature is useful for transpilation that requires comments remain relatively close to the source: e.g. ***files under test with istanbul-ignore coverage annotations***."

Comment: Thank you for the reference, unfortunately it does not seem to resolve the issue I was having :/ I posted another question following up on this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71564063/can-i-get-next-js-to-exclude-babelrc-during-build