# Can I Get Next.Js to exclude .babelrc during build?

Tags: next.js, babeljs, swc-compiler

I'd like to not include .babelrc during build since SWC is disabled as a replacement for Babel. I only need .babelrc for a plugin for dev testing purposes that is not supported by SWC yet. I am told to check [the doc about ignored compiler options](https://next.js.org/docs/messages/ignored-compiler-options) but the page is down, and I could not find a solution from the [nextjs document on disabling SWC](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled) and its [feedback thread](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/30174).

[image: Disabling SWC as replacement for Babel]
[image: Ignored Compiler Options Next.js page down]

Answer (score 5):

Super hacky, but you could modify the `build` script in `package.json` to temporarily rename the config file before the build then restore it after:

```json
{

  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "mv .babelrc .babel_ && next build; mv .babel_ .babelrc",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  }

}
```

It's not a cross-platform solution, however.

Comment: Will this ignore code coverage during the build?

Comment: But when you run `npm run dev` you got the same issue?

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin I don't use Babel, so I don't the know how this workaround affects your situation. You might get better answers over at [Next's discussion forum](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions).

Answer (score 3):

I think you can add `.babelrc` to `.gitignore`, and it won't be used during build.

Comment: I still want to commit .babelrc to my git repo though

Comment: @EdenChan for this specific case, then i think you can use Mark's solution