# How can I instrument code in Cypress with SWC (not babel) in Next.js?

Tags: cypress, babeljs, next.js13, swc-compiler

I integrated Cypress into my project for testing, and everything went well. However, when I want to make code coverage I could not find a solution for my issue.

In Next.js 13, it does not support `.babelrc`, but [SWC](https://swc.rs/). However, *[Istanbul](https://istanbul.js.org/)* requires `.babelrc` as configuration!

Please read this [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/30174).

If I configure `.babelrc` and run my Cypress tests and build scripts:

```json
  "cypress-open-component": "cypress open --component",

  "cypress-open-e2e": "npm run instrument && cypress open --e2e",

  "cypress-run-component": "npm run instrument && cypress run --component --spec src/components/core/*/*.cy.tsx --headless",

  "instrument": "npx nyc instrument --compact=false src  instrumented",

  "coverage-report": "npx nyc report --reporter=html"

  "build": "mv .babelrc.js .babel_ && next build; mv .babel_ .babelrc.js",

  "start": "next start",

  "lint": "next lint",
```

They work well.

However, when I run `npm run dev`:

```json
"dev": "next dev",
```

I got an error:

```
 info Using external babel configuration from /home/alaeddine/Desktop/gersthofen-app/.babelrc.js
- error ./src/app/layout.tsx:2:1
Syntax error: "next/font" requires SWC although Babel is being used due to a custom babel config being present.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/babel-font-loader-conflict
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Restoring pack failed from /home/alaeddine/Desktop/gersthofen-app/.next/cache/webpack/client-development-fallback.pack.gz: Error: incorrect header check
- wait compiling /_error (client and server)...
- error ./src/app/layout.tsx:2:1
Syntax error: "next/font" requires SWC although Babel is being used due to a custom babel config being present.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/babel-font-loader-conflict
```

for the build script I used [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71564063/can-i-get-next-js-to-exclude-babelrc-during-build), but I see it as a tricky solution.

#### Two alternatives

If I change the `.babelrc.js` to `.babelrc.build.js`, the `npm run dev` works well, because it ignores the Babel file, but the Cypress one failed:

`npm run cypress-run-component`

```
(Run Starting)

  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ Cypress:        12.17.3                                                                        │
  │ Browser:        Electron 106 (headless)                                                        │
  │ Node Version:   v18.15.0 (/home/alaeddine/.nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/bin/node)                │
  │ Specs:          1 found (indexButton.cy.tsx)                                                   │
  │ Searched:       src/components/core/Button/indexButton.cy.tsx                                  │
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

  Running:  indexButton.cy.tsx                                                              (1 of 1)
17 assets
65 modules

ERROR in ./src/components/core/Button/index.tsx:14:1
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  12 |   loading,
  13 |   icon,
> 14 | }: IButtonProps) => {
     |  ^
  15 |   const {
  16 |     button,
  17 |     primary,

client (webpack 5.86.0) compiled with 1 error in 6654 ms


  1) An uncaught error was detected outside of a test
```

Please, how can I make code coverage in Next.js 13 with Cypress?

#### File *cypress.config.ts*

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: "next",
      bundler: "webpack",
      webpackConfig: {
        mode: "development",
        devtool: false,
        module: {
          rules: [
            // application and Cypress files are bundled like React components
            // and instrumented using the babel-plugin-istanbul
            // (we will filter the code coverage for non-application files later)
            {
              test: /\.tsx$/,
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              use: {
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
                  plugins: [
                    // we could optionally insert this plugin
                    // only if the code coverage flag is on
                    "istanbul",
                  ],
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    // Instrument the code
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      require("@cypress/code-coverage/task")(on, config);

      return config;
    },
  },

  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },
  video: false,
});
```

#### File *next.config.ts*

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  async rewrites() {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
      return [
        {
          source: "/components",
          destination: "/page",
        },
      ];
    }

    return [];
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using swc-plugin-coverage-instrument.

1. **Create Coverage**. I suggest following [Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage). Ignore the Babel instructions. Set up @cypress/code-coverage. While you test run, it should say something about coverage. The image is in the documentation.
2. **Instrument you code**. I suggest using swc-plugin-coverage-instrument. So the steps would be:

   ```
   yarn add --dev swc-plugin-coverage-instrument

   next.config.js
     experimental: {
       swcPlugins: [["swc-plugin-coverage-instrument", {}]],
     },
   ```

   ```
   // Launch Next.js
   server yarn run dev
   // Launch Cypress
   npx cypress open
   Run Tests
   Open Coverage report at coverage/lcov-report/index.html
   ```

   It even works with app-router with some adjustments [here](https://github.com/mike-plummer/nextjs-cypress-ct-example/issues/1).

Here are [some examples](https://github.com/mike-plummer/nextjs-cypress-ct-example).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35357409)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I updated my answer based on your feedback.

Comment: I removed the accepted answer because I found that issue with the SWC plugin when I run npm run dev.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/44433

Comment: Have you tried the fix that I mentioned in the post? https://github.com/mike-plummer/nextjs-cypress-ct-example/issues/1 Also there is an easy workarounds for next/font like downloading and adding fonts into fonts folder and use it.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/kwonoj/swc-plugin-coverage-instrument

You could use SWC's port of Istanbul; however, this issue is pretty important IMO: https://github.com/kwonoj/swc-plugin-coverage-instrument/issues/197

Alternatively, you could use babel, but just for `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test';` (see [Can I Get Next.Js to exclude .babelrc during build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71564063/can-i-get-next-js-to-exclude-babelrc-during-build))